# How to retain scope data while traversing between various controllers

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have a download function, which has a promise called onProgress(which returns download percentage), I want to go to some other view and come back. Even though controller's scope is with proper data the page is not getting refreshed with new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with this vague description it sounds like the onProgress() function is not in "angular world". Therefore, any changes to $scope that you make in the promise callback will not be noticed by angular until the next digest cycle.

The solution is easy: inside the onProgress() promise callback, wrap your changes to $scope in $apply:

```
onProgress().then(function(percent)
{
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // your changes to $scope here, so that angular notices them
    }
}
```